# Do Ink-jet printers emit harmful particles into the air?

Tags: inkjet-printer, work-environment

They say laser printers emit toxic particles into the air.
[Laser printer without harmful emissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/257984/laser-printer-without-harmful-emissions)

How about ink-jet printers? I am using an ink-jet printer in my room. As it is a cold winter, I usually keep my window shut. Is there scientific research on the extent to which inkjet printers release any substances into the air that could be harmful in those concentrations? I searched Google for this, but could not find any information about inkjet printers (all results were talking about laser printers).

Comment: With inkjets, the actual amount of ink ejected is infinitesimal (consider how long a tiny cartridge lasts).  The amount of ink that does not get adhered to the paper is a miniscule fraction of that, and the portion of ink that is something other than solvents is a tiny fraction of the miniscule fraction.  What ends up in the air is evaporated solvents when the ink dries, and those are substances that you get orders of magnitude more exposure to from common household things.

Comment: You worry too much. Seriously.

Comment: A quick Google search for "Inkjet emissions" gave me a few decent results. IE: ["Calculating VOCs from inkjet printing"](http://www.pmai.org/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=5096), ["Polluting printers contaminate office air"](http://www.environmentalhealth.ca/fall07PollutingPrinters.html)

Comment: This morning I walked from the train station to the office. I do this almost every weekday of the year. All those car/bus/truck exhaust fumes I'm breathing in... day after day... put's your ink worries into perspective don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, those are all toxic. I just did not want to add another on top of them. Just like there are no people who think like "I've already inhaled a lot of car fumes today. I'm going to smoke a cigarette because it wouldn't make any difference."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really comes down to the ink you [use](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/printer-ink-toxic-58156.html).

> The primary ingredients in most printer inks are water, ethylene glycol and alcohol. Printer ink is about as safe as dish washing soap. Drinking it can make you sick, but it is not life threatening. If you have questions about the toxicity of a particular brand of ink, all companies publish Material Safety Data Sheets for their products. These are usually available on their websites and they will tell you what the ink contains. Inks used in commercial printing processes however, may contain toxic metals.

Comment: Drinking it may not be harmful, but what about inhaling it?

Comment: Im not a doctor, but I play one on TV.  There is so little ink actually being sprayed, I doubt there is much going into the air.  Im would suspect you are getting more harmful chemicals from your hairspray.

Comment: If I stop snorting ink, will the funny colors on my nose eventually wash off?  :-)